# Why does my listView doesn't show inserted rows?

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a custom cursorAdapter that is certainly missing something, because when I add a item in the database, it isn't shown on the listView, but if I relaunch the application, it show added rows.

Here are my activity and my customAdapter :

```
package com.android.adapter;

import com.android.activity.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ADD_NOTE_BOTTOM = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_ADD_NOTE_TOP = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_ADD_NOTE_TOP + 1;

    public NotesCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean flag){
        super(context, cursor, flag);
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context con, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView content = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.note);
        content.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content_note")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context con, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup vp) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_note, vp, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;

    }

}


package com.android.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.adapter.NotesCursorAdapter;
import com.android.database.NoteDataSource;

public class EverydayNotesAndroid3Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Cursor cursorNotes;
    private NoteDataSource dataNoteConnector;
    private NotesCursorAdapter notesCursorAdapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        activity = this;

        dataNoteConnector = new NoteDataSource(activity);

        dataNoteConnector.open();

        cursorNotes = dataNoteConnector.getAllNotes();

        startManagingCursor(cursorNotes);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);

        notesCursorAdapter = new NotesCursorAdapter(activity, cursorNotes, true);

        listView.setAdapter(notesCursorAdapter);

        Button b = new Button(activity);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                cursorNotes = dataNoteConnector.createNoteTop("American Alex is god");
                cursorNotes.requery();
                System.out.println("and everyone should listen to him");


//              notesCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursorNotes); // automatically closes old Cursor
//              notesCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

}
```

Thanks for paying attention.

EDIT : I've found a solution but I hate it, I wish there were an other solution.

Now I have in my activity :

```
cursorNotes = dataNoteConnector.createNoteTop("American Alex is god");

                cursorNotes = dataNoteConnector.getAllNotes();

                notesCursorAdapter = new NotesCursorAdapter(activity, cursorNotes, true);

                listView.setAdapter(notesCursorAdapter);
```

I find it insane, there should be a simpler way to update the list after an update. Here, I'm recreating a cursor, recreating a cursorAdapter that I feed with the new cursor, an then affect this cursorAdapter to the listView. This is as the notepad example from android doc, but I'm sure there is a way to update the the adapter and the listView just by manipulating the cursor, but I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Google has to say about requery()

> This method is deprecated. Don't use this. Just request a new cursor,
>   so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the
>   new cursor comes back.

You can check it out here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

So they actually suggest you do what you have done. :) But if you still want to do it the other way, uncomment the notesCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Ideally requery() is supposed to call the noifydatasetchange(), but I have observed that an explicit call is required to refresh the list.

Answer (score 1):

try un commenting the last line in your activity

```
adapter.notifydatasetcanged();
```

Comment: No ... Thought requery function would automatically upgrade the cursor inside the adapter and upgrade the listView, but even uncommenting the datasetchanged doesn't work ...

Comment: ok then try this it's messy and cheap but it works start this activity using self intent i.e new Intent(alpha.this,alpha.class);finish(); in this way ur activity would restart and your list will be updated

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to do it easily ... I edited my post because I figured out a bad solution, I'll post again if I find what is bad in my code. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

well i won't recommend @Aashish solution. the best thing would be to make you listview and adapter member variables and then recreate adapter

```
private ListView listView;
private ListAdapter notesCursorAdapter;
private Cursor cursorNotes;

private void update() {
notesCursorAdapter = new NotesCursorAdapter(activity, cursorNotes, true); 
listView.setAdapter(notesCursorAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's better to recreate an adapter than just switch the new cursor to the same adapter ?

Comment: creating new adapter doesn't really add anymore overhead on operating system as it releases the old adapter. Creating new Cursor will cause it to rerun the query and then redraw. So yes I vote for creating new adapter.